# how to fix : Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I try input my name into scanner but it throws an exception:

```
Username is: danny

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at NonDuplicateCharacters.main(NonDuplicateCharacters.java:10)
```

my input

```
danny
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
```

expected output

```
danny
4
```

my code:

```
import java.util.*;  
public class NonDuplicateCharacters {  
     public static void main(String[] args) {  
     Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
     String userName = myObj.nextLine(); 
     System.out.print("Username is: " + userName);
    
    
        Scanner input1= new Scanner(System.in);
        String number = input1.nextLine();
        int count;  
          
        
        char string[] = number.toCharArray();  
          
        
        for(int i = 0; i <string.length; i++) {  
            count = 1;  
            for(int j = i+1; j <string.length; j++) {  
                if(string[i] == string[j] && string[i] != ' ') {  
                    count++;  
                    string[j] = '0';  
                }  
            }  
           
            if(count == 1 && string[i] != '0' && string[i] != ' ')  
                System.out.println(string[i]);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

i read solution to change nextline() next(), i try but it doesnt work. sorry for bad grammar

Comment: The name in the stacktrace doesn't match the name in the code. The output above your stack trace doesn't match what's in your code (there's no "Username is :" prompt anywhere). There's no call to `Scanner.nextLine` on line 10 of your code. So as it stands it's really hard to debug your problem, since you didn't give us the code that causes the problem.

Comment: You stacktrace tells us to look at "NonDuplicateCharacters" class. But the code you provided  DuplicateCharacters.

Comment: im sorry, im new java learner. learn from online but try to use java code. i didnt mean to fool you mr. im sorry.

Comment: sir, the code is from https://www.javatpoint.com/program-to-find-the-duplicate-characters-in-a-string. i learn to make not duplicate. by find character. if character find > 1 is will be counted for duplicate

Comment: and code to input from user i learn from https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp. im sorry i didnt mean to fool. im just learning. it hard self learn. but im thankfull for your reponse sir. sorry for my grammar

Comment: @Rin check my answer please. tried it on my local machine. it works.

Comment: It's fine to be new and learning, that's not the issue. But the information that you posted simply didn't fit together, which made it hard to answer. In the future please ensure that you fully recreate the problem once and *then* copy all the relevant information (code, input/output) into your post at once to make sure they match. Ideally by providing an [mre], which you were pretty close to already.

Comment: mr @vuisal i used https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/ idk still have exeption. i read post about scanner. i try to implement nextLine() to next() but exeption massage still running

Comment: Try `nextInt()` to read the integer. That's what it's for. But in general you should never call `Scanner.nextXXX()` unless `Scanner.hasNextXXX()` returns true, for any XXX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating two `Scanner` objects based on `System.in`.

Each `Scanner` will *read* from `System.in` and consume some of its input. That means that the first one might have already read some things into its buffer when you created the second one.

The short answer is: never create multiple `Scanner` objects based on the same parameter, simply continue using the existing scanner. For example this would fix your issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
     Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     String userName = myScanner.nextLine(); 
     System.out.print("Username is: " + userName);
    
    
     String number = myScanner.nextLine();
     // ... rest of your code ...
```

Comment: It is not the problem with Scanner. I just copied his code, and parsed into Intellij. Works absolutely fine.

Comment: It is his online compiler. It does not work properly.

Comment: never used multiple scanner objects based on the same parameter. noted sir